# Log Access Login on Pentaho 6.0

Tags: logging, authentication, pentaho

In Pentaho 6.0
Is it possible to retrieve login information for any user?
It will be awesome if you can log even the resource runned, but simply the login should be fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the PentahoAuditLog you can find information about user login. The file can be found ..\biserver-ce\pentaho-solutions\system\logs\audit

from:
http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?217578-Log-Access-Login-on-Penthao-6-0